# Carregar/ler/usar arquivo jar via web

Tags: java

É possível carregar/ler/usar um jar via web sem ter que baixa-lo e usar no classpath?

Caso seja possível como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, mas é uma tarefa complexa e delicada, não recomendada para a maioria dos casos, e que possui várias limitações.

Basicamente, você pode carregar novas classes manualmente, por exemplo, através do método [`loadClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) de um `ClassLoader`.

O problema é que dentro de uma aplicação Java Web geralmente há uma hierarquia de *ClassLoaders* e a forma como você vai carregar classes depende de vários fatores e de como elas serão usadas.

É possível usar a classe mais especializada [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html), a qual permite especificar Jars e diretórios no construtor, sendo que as classe serão automaticamente localizadas quando você chamar o método `loadClass` ou equivalente.

Criar um novo `ClassLoader` permite a você isolar as classes carregadas, que não poderão acessar as classes normais do sistema. Isso pode ser desejável ou não. Uma vantagem de usar um novo `ClassLoader` é que se ele não for mais usado e coletado pelo *Garbage Collector*, as classes carregadas serão eliminadas também.

Por outro lado, se você quiser carregar as classes como parte do seu programa, pode tentar usar o `ClassLoader` atual da sua aplicação web. Porém, neste caso, a classe nunca mais será descarregada da memória (pelo menos numa JVM regular).

Uma alternativa a isso é usar o padrão OSGi, no qual você pode carregar e descarregar módulos *on-the-fly*.

Em suma, dá mas é complexo e pode levar a problemas sérios. Seria interessante saber exatamente o objetivo de fazer isso para determinar se é realmente necessário, o método mais adequado e se o esforço vale a pena.